# Selenium: Test fails when element is not on page

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to find a way that if element id visible then do the following but it is failing with an error

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Code is trying first to find an element but element does not exist so it gives me above error how can I fix this issue.?

```
public void Test()
{
        if(IsElementVisible(Driver.FindELement...)
        {
            //do something
        }
}


public bool IsElementVisible(IWebElement element)
{
    return element.Displayed;
}
```

Comment: avoid logic in your tests and implement each test to validate a single behavior.

Comment: The reason why I have added like this is because it is like a registration form for different client having same code but some field does not exist in few client side page. That's why I have a apply such logic and condition to check and continue with other steps.

Comment: then implement a registration method for each type of client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the element is null before trying to access the .Displayed property, change your IsElementVisible method to this:

```
public bool IsElementVisible(IWebElement element)
{
    return element == null ? false : element.Displayed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate that.